# How to define signs for angular velocity, acceleration and torques?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, conventions, torque, angular-velocity

I get confused how to define signs of angular velocity, acceleration and torques in the cases like the following.

[image]

We have a disk with radius $r$ and center of mass at point $CM$ shifted $d$ from the disk center. The disk stands on a sleepless surface.
If we push slightly top of the dist, it starts small oscillation around equilibrium point.

As I understand rotating torque is $( d m g\ sin \theta -  r F_{fr})$ where $F_{fr}$ is a friction force (as there is no slipping between the disk and surface).
According the the second law for rotation:
$$ d m g \ sin \theta -  r F_{fr} = I \dot{\omega}$$
and for small $\theta$:
$$ d m g \theta -  r F_{fr} = I \ddot{\theta}$$

$F_{fr}$ creates linear acceleration of the disk to the left side and the second law for disk translation:
$$F_{fr} = m \dot{v}$$
As there is no slipping: $ v = r \omega$.

Eventually for oscillations I would expect to get equation looks like: $\ddot {\theta} + z\ \theta = 0$

Now comes confusing part: what happens with signs here ...

I understand that as result of rotation $\theta$ gets decreased. So $\omega$ is negative. Right?

Does it mean that $ v = - r \omega$?

And if resulting torque decreases the $\theta$ does it mean that the right equation is:
$$ - (d m g \theta -  F_{fr} r) = I \ddot{\theta}$$ and thus
$$ - (d m g \theta -  ( - r \ddot{\theta} m r)) = I \ddot{\theta}$$
Is it a right way of thinking? What rules should we use for cases like this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a few labels and a set of axes to your diagram.

[image]

It is the arrow that you have assigned to the angle $\theta$ which determines the positive direction for $\theta$ - clockwise - and in terms of an angular rotation and using the right hand Cartesian system one might write the rotation as $\theta\, \hat z$ where $\hat z$ is the unit vector into the screen.

The torque due to the frictional force about the centre $B$ is $F_{\rm fr}\,r\,\hat z$ and that due to the weight of the mass $m$ is $-mgd\sin \theta \, \hat z$

The equation of motion is $F_{\rm fr}\,r\,\hat z-mgd\sin \theta \, \hat z = I \dot \omega \,\hat z \Rightarrow F_{\rm fr}\,r-mgd\sin \theta  = I \dot \omega =I \ddot \theta$

About the point of contact $A$ ,  $\vec v = \vec \omega \times \vec r =(\omega \,\hat z) \times (r \,\hat y) = - \omega \,r\,\hat x = v\,\hat x$

which is what you might expect in that moving to the left results in a decrease in the angle $\theta$ ie the component of the angular velocity $\omega$ is negative when the component of the translational velocity $v$ is positive.

Comment: Regarding torques I got the idea. 
Regarding point A, do you mean that linear velocity of point A due to rotation is
$$
\vec{v}_A = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} = (\omega \hat{z}) \times (-r \hat{y}) = 
(-\omega r) (\hat{z}\hat{y}) = -\omega r (-\hat{x}) = \omega r \hat{x}
$$
Linear velocity of point B $$\vec{v}_B = v\hat{x} = - \vec{v}_A = - \omega r \hat{x}$$
So, 
$$ F_{fr} = mg \dot{v} = mg(-\dot{\omega} r) = - mg \ddot{\theta} r$$ and finally

$$ - mg \ddot{\theta} r^2 - mgd sin \theta = I\ddot{\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\let\th=\theta \def\dth{\dot\th }\def\ddth{\ddot\th} \def\ns#1#2{#1_{\mathrm#2}} \def\xA{\ns xA} \def\yA{\ns yA}
\def\xB{\ns xB} \def\bW{\mathbf W} \def\D#1#2{{d#1 \over d#2}}$
I'd like to keep signs and axes as @Farcher did, but I'm afraid
confusion could arise because rotation $x \to y$ is clockwise, instead
of counterclockwise as usual. So I'll change $y$ orientation, taking
it positive downwards. As a consequence I define $\th$ not as in
figure, but by CM's $(x,y)$ coordinates:
$$\eqalign{
    x &= \xB + d\,\cos\th \cr
    y &= d\,\sin\th.\cr}$$

Now for a more physical issue. It's not allowed to write equation of
motion computing moments wrt B. Only the following choices are correct:

- to take CM as reference point
- to take any other point having a velocity vector parallel to CM's
  velocity
- as a special case, to take any fixed point (zero velocity is
  parallel to any other vector).

B doesn't satisfy above conditions. Among legitimate points the best
choice is A, which in pure rolling motion is instantaneously at rest
and has the additional advantage that we haven't to worry about reaction force of the plane surface. It's applied in A, so that its momentum identically vanishes.

So the only external force is weight $\bW$, having only a $y$-component 
$W_y = m\,g$. Its moment wrt A has a $z$ component
$$M_z = (x - \xA)\,W_y = m\,g\,d\,\cos\th.$$

In order to be able to write the equation of motion we need the moment
of inertia wrt A (more precisely, wrt an axis through A parallel to
$z$). The question says nothing about moments of inertia, nor about
mass. It's therefore necessary to introduce convenient symbols and
leave them as undetermined parameters.

Let's call $I_0$ the moment of inertia wrt CM, $m$ the disk's mass. Then Huygens' theorem says
$$I = I_0 + m\,s^2$$
where $s$ is the distance of A from CM. We have
$$\eqalign{
  s^2 &= (x - \xA)^2 + (y - \yA)^2 = 
           d^2 \cos^2\!\th  + (d\,\sin\th - r)^2 \cr
      &= d^2 + r^2 - 2\,d\,r\,\sin\th \cr}$$

Our equation of motion is simply 
$$\D{}t (I\,\dot\th) = M_z.\tag1$$
It's worth while noting that angular velocity is the same around any
axis. This is the reason why, even though the axis of rotation is
through A, we may write $\dot\th$ for angular velocity.

Expanding (1)
$$\D It\,\dth + I\,\ddth = m\,g\,d\,\cos\th$$
$$2\,m\,d\,r\,\cos\th\>\dth^2 + I\,\ddth = m\,g\,d\,\cos\th.$$
In order to study small oscillation we must observe that the
equilibrium position is $\th=\pi/2$. Then it's expedient to define
$$\th = {\pi \over 2} + \phi$$
which gives
$$I = I_0 + m\,(d^2 + r^2 - 2\,d\,r\,\cos\phi)$$
and
$$-2\,m\,d\,r\,\sin\phi\>\dot\phi^2 + I\,\ddot\phi = 
  -m\,g\,d\,\sin\phi.$$

Now we can linearize in $\phi$, i.e. neglect terms of order above the
first in $\phi$ or its derivatives:
$$I_1 \ddot\phi = -m\,g\,d\,\phi \tag2$$
where
$$I_1 = I_0 + m\,(d - r)^2.$$

Eq. (2) is different from the one you wrote in comment. I leave for
you to find why.

Comment: it's different, I guess, as $I_0$ wrt CM and in my comment $I$ wrt point $B$

Comment: Regarding you note "It's not allowed to write equation of motion computing moments wrt B". Do you mean translation movement only or rotation as well? I thought we could use rotation equation wrt B.

Comment: @vov *it's different, I guess, as $I_0$ wrt CM and in my comment $I$
wrt point B* I wouldn't say so. Your equation (corrected for a $g$ in
excess) is $-m \ddot\theta r^2 - m g d \sin\theta = I \ddot\theta$. My
eq. (2) (which is linearized) contains $I_1$, different from $I_0+m
r^2$.

Comment: @vov I'm not sure what you mean writing *Do you mean translation
movement only or rotation as well? I thought we could use rotation
equation wrt B.* If translation and rotation is what I would call
"equation for resultant of forces" and "equation for resultant
moments" then no, you may not use B for the latter. In general you may
not take a point at your pleasure. Only a resting point or one whose
velocity is parallel to that of CM.